# How to get the type of a property in Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

In Boost Graph Library (BGL), how can I programmatically get the type of a property such as the one associated with `boost::edge_weight_t`?

I searched and found lots of examples on how to get the type of the ***property map***, but not the type of the property itself. For example, [BGL documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html) below has the type of the property map for `edge_weight_t` as `property_map<DirectedGraph, edge_weight_t>::type`:

```
typedef ... DirectedGraph;
DirectedGraph digraph(V);
{
  ..
  property_map<DirectedGraph, edge_weight_t>::type
    weight = get(edge_weight, digraph);
}
```

But how do I get the type of the weight of the edges? (`float`, `int` etc.)

How do I declare variables for the edge weights with appropriate type expressions (??? below), so that I can, e.g., read into these weight values from a file/stream.

```
typedef ... DirectedGraph;
...
??? w;
input_s >> w;
```

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/property_map/blob/develop/example/example1.cpp#L15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in comments by @llonesmiz, for a property map type

```
typedef property_map<Graph, boost::edge_weight_t>::type WeightMap
```

the type of the property (weight) value can be retrieved with `property_traits` as:

```
typedef typename boost::property_traits<WeightMap>::value_type edge_weight_type;
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `::type` or `::const_type`?

Comment: In a shorthand, `template <typename Tag, typename Graph> using propval_t = typename boost::property_traits<typename property_map<Graph, Tag>::type>::value_type;` or something. Mind you, I'm quoting from memory.

Comment: I had already +1-ed. And now we will even confuse fewer future visitors :)